# Lost Windows 8 installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I installed Ubuntu latest version and it works but lost my Windows.  When I was doing installation from USB boot. I chose the typical installation because there was no other operating system found.  I think I might have formatted the hard drive. I lost windows 8. Can anyone help

I think windows 8 is in there but I do not know how to access it

Comment: If you formatted the entire disc you will have to re-install Windows. Remember to choose the option "install side my side".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use disk utility to verify if you still have the partition where you installed windows 8 or if you have formatted windows 8 partition. If disk utility is not available among you apps, you can download it from software centre.

If windows 8 partition does not exist, then you will have to install windows 8 or if your system have build in recovery or restore tool, you can restore back windows 8. Now if you are restoring back your system, you will loose the Ubuntu installation.

Or if you are installing a fresh copy of windows 8, you can partition your hard drive and set the desired amount of space for windows 8, install windows and and restore grub.

Hope this might help you.

Comment: I tried windows recovery but I can not because windows 8 is not there. Is there any way I can bring it back. Disk utility cpsay there is a partition about the same size of my hard drive. Could this be windows 8. If so how do I get into it.

Comment: Please, post image of your partitions for us to see what can be done.